# How do you make it so when an Input has a value under 4, it will make a text go up and make them do it over 4?

Tags: html

I'm making a Sign Up Page, and I'd want it so if the password is under 4 characters, it'd tell them the password needs to be 4 or up characters.

I've tried searching for this, there's no answer. I've tried multiple websites.

`<input type="password" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">`

I expect, when testing for the minimum  to be 4 and the maximum to be 8, but when I put an value of 3 into the input, there's no message.

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs to exist within a `<form>` tag:

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
</form>
```

In the above example, enter less than four characters and hit enter while in the field and you'll see the browser's built-in message.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally when typing it I did "text" instead of "password"

Comment: @Sushii The answer is still the same